# ROC curve with only positive and negative test results but without the ground truth

Tags: roc

I have a data based on images.

1. The diagnostic test result based on images to decide positive test result or negative test result.
2. I do not have background and knowledge about the history of data. In other words, I do not know if each cases are truly diseased or truly healthy.

How can I find cut-off points here to distinguish between True positive rate and False positive rate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out which cases are truly diseased or healthy. This is called the "ground truth" and you need it in order to distinguish between true and false positive cases. This is absolutely unavoidable.

No software can or will ever allow you to compute a ROC curve without knowing the ground truth. There's simply no way around it.